# How to pass parameter into silverlight so that it is "behind the scenes"

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, xaml

I'm brand new to learning Silverlight/XAML/C#.

I'm using an ASP.NET function to pass a string parameter to a Silverlight App. Currently I'm using the following code to simply verify that it works when the Silverlight App is loaded:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtIP" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

How do I set up an element that's "behind the scenes" that doesn't necessarily display in the XAML?  I thought about simply hiding the TextBlock, but I imagine there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a Silverlight application using the initParams option in the plugin.  Load that with some ASPNET code and you can dynamically set it at load time.

Comment: Tim, you are ubiquitous :-). I like the idea of using initParams, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pass my javascript variable on the ASP.NET page into the HTML.  Since the ASP:Silverlight control was removed from the Silverlight 3 SDK, I'm not exactly sure what to do. Am I going to have to write the whole line in Javascript? Ideas?

Comment: Ok, that took way too long, but I figured out I could use the <% %> feature in ASP.Net.  Like I said, I'm new to this.  However, using the initParams options is much nicer than what I had before.

Answer (score 0):

For further information on how to pass initParams into a Silverlight, check out Tim's video demonstration on InitParams here: [Using Startup Parameters with Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/using-startup-parameters-with-silverlight/).

Also, check out my blog post where I cover several of the details in Tim's video and show what to do with the data once it's in the Silverlight App: [Pass the IP Address of a User to Silverlight as a Parameter](http://benmccormack.com/?p=25/).