# Silverlight InitParams prompting to install Silverlight in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, mozilla

I have a problem with a Silverlight control's behavior in an ASP.NET page. The control works OK within IE, but in Mozilla, I get the 'install Microsoft Silverlight' message.

After some try/fail sessions, I came to the conclusion that I get that message in Mozilla only if I use the `<param name="InitParams"/>` param in my Silverlight control. If I delete the param, it's all OK.

Has anyone had this issue before ?

**ASP.NET page code:**

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <object  data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="source" value="http://server/domain/ClientBin/MyName.xap" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: just curious, but why are you supplying `<param name="InitParams"/>` if you are not supplying `value="..."` within the same tag? `InitParams` are used to pass values into the application from the loading page. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363554/how-to-pass-parameter-into-silverlight-so-that-it-is-behind-the-scenes for more details.  If you don't need `InitParams`, don't use the `InitParams` tag within the object.

Comment: I need params, I didn't post the value here, the complete tag is : <param name="InitParam" value="<%=PropertyName %>/> and the property is in the server side code.

I found an workaround, getting some values from query string, directly from silverlight control. But I still have this question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I have resolved the issue. At least I have figured out the problem.
If I have '/> param in my silverlight object.

The InitParams property servers side works in any way in IE. But in Mozilla, if the InitParams property ( which is a string ) is null or string.empty, Mozilla doesn't render the silverlight application, only the download silverlight frame.

This is very strange, because the html result from the .asp page is the same in every browser.
Anyway, if InitParams has a value, all is working great. So I think, for the moment, this is the right solution, just add some dummy value in there.

Comment: I also noticed this problem some time ago. Look at number two here: http://frenk.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/two-silverlight-3-gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy to test, but the param name is not InitParams but rather **i**nitParams. Perhaps IE is more forgiving of the casing.

[Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: I tested with initParams and the problem is still there.
Actually the problem appears when I use something like <param name="initParams" value='<%=InitParams %>...so, when I try to use some server side property to bind the value to that.